# Docker - can't connect to MySQL container

Tags: mysql, spring, docker

I'm using Docker Compose to containerize my Spring Microservices application.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysqldb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=cabDB
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
    volumes:
      - mysqldb:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always

  discovery-server:
    image: discovery-server:latest
    container_name: discovery-server
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    restart: always

  api-gateway:
    image: api-gateway:latest
    container_name: api-gateway
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK_SECURITY=TRACE
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
    links:
      - discovery-server
    restart: always

  payment-service:
    container_name: payment-service
    image: payment-service:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
      - mysqldb
    links:
      - mysqldb
      - discovery-server
    restart: always
volumes:
  mysqldb:
```

application.yml in payment-service

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${MYSQL_JDBC_URL:jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/cabDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false}
    username: ${MYSQL_USERNAME:user}
    password: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:pass}
  application:
    name: PAYMENT-SERVICE
```

So, if I run **docker compose up -d**, I get this error in all services that trying connect to mysqldb: **Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.**
But if I use:

```
docker exec -it *mysql container id* bash
mysql -uuser -ppass
```

All works corrected.

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up -d` again, does it work the second time?  It's possible the application can start up before the database is ready.  Also consider removing the obsolete `links:` and `expose:` lines from your configuration, which potentially could interfere with standard Docker networking.  You don't need to replace these with anything, just delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to add a health check for mysql.
Because it may take some time to start and services have already tried to connect to mysql

and add depends_on like this:
depends_on:
mysqldb:
condition: service_healthy